# Delivering retouched photos to passerby participants of photo booth?

Tags: post-processing, instagram

This question is more about distributing photos.

I'm going to work at pop-up photos booth at an event. I'm going to use my own camera and maybe participants' smartphones should they ask me.

The booth sponsor is looking for a way to get participants to post photos on Instagram for brand exposure on social media.
If the photos are taken by participants' phones, they can post it immediately after the shoot.

However, if I take the photos on my camera, **what's the best way to deliver the retouched photos to participants and get them to post on Instagram?**

I'm thinking of the following:

- Take note of the participants' Instagram IDs and time of photo taken
- Match the identity of participants later by referencing the note
- Message the identified participants via Instagram DM and share photo

For good measure to encourage participants to post, I'll ask the sponsor to host a giveaway where you can enter by posting their photo on Instagram and tagging the sponsor's account

Comment: Post to some server, display QRcode for URL of photo on server